# why isnt inner join working on related tables

Tags: sql

i have 2 related tables :

- s_user ( username, email, password , level )
- user_levels (level_id , level_name )

i want it so that the level in s_user displays the level_name from user_levels. instead of just a number

---

I've tried inner join not working tho

```
SELECT s_users.username, s_users.email , user_level.level_name
From s_users INNER JOIN
     user_level
     ON s_users.user_id = user_level.level_id;
```

Comment: `user_id = level_id` looks highly suspicious.  Check your `JOIN` conditions.

Comment: Does `user_id` equal a `level_id`? Maybe `level` should equal `level_id`

Comment: What is "level"?  Did you mean for that to say "level_name"?  What is the relation between s_user and user_levels?

Comment: and without sample data hard to tell something rigid.

Comment: @Phaelaxz level is in s_user and its related to level_id in user_levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `level` in the `s_user` table is the `level_id` you want to lookup in the `user_level` table, try this:

```sql
SELECT s_users.username, s_users.email , user_level.level_name
FROM s_users INNER JOIN user_level ON s_users.level = user_level.level_id;
```

Comment: perfect , worked excellent..
Thank you!!